# Sum same column with different conditions then Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to sum the same `column` but with *different* conditions and the group then all by `"Cliente"` (ID)

When I use

```
SELECT Cliente, SUM([Valor Original]) As Emitidos FROM TAB_Documentos WHERE Condição = 0 GROUP BY Cliente
```

I get this result, but I need to join/union with `"Baixados"`, `"Devolvidos"`, `"Outros"` and then **group** them all by `"Cliente"`...

[image]

I'm trying to figure out **how to join that SQL string**... Is basicly what I need, but I need them all together...

```
SELECT Cliente, SUM([Valor Original]) As Emitidos FROM TAB_Documentos WHERE Condição = 0 GROUP BY Cliente
SELECT Cliente, SUM([Valor Original]) As Baixados FROM TAB_Documentos WHERE Condição = 1 GROUP BY Cliente
SELECT Cliente, SUM([Valor Original]) As Devolvidos FROM TAB_Documentos WHERE Condição = 2 GROUP BY Cliente
SELECT Cliente, SUM([Valor Original]) As OutrosFROM TAB_Documentos WHERE Condição = 3 GROUP BY Cliente
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the filters inside the aggregate function, instead of using a `WHERE` clause...

*(This is often termed as `conditional aggregation`.)*

```
SELECT
  Cliente,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Condição = 0 THEN [Valor Original] END) As Emitidos,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Condição = 1 THEN [Valor Original] END) As Baixados,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Condição = 2 THEN [Valor Original] END) As Devolvidos,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Condição = 3 THEN [Valor Original] END) As Outros
FROM
  TAB_Documentos
GROUP BY
  Cliente
```

However, SQL is often much better suited to normalised data. For example, the simplest query is actually...

```
SELECT
  Cliente,
  Condição,
  SUM([Valor Original]) AS [Valor]
FROM
  TAB_Documentos
GROUP BY
  Cliente,
  Condição
```

While this isn't the format you asked for, it's shorter and easier to reuse in subsequent SQL; it's the way SQL is *designed* to be written.

Comment: Awesome... I do have another question... I need a 5th sum which return the average value (by "Cliente") of column "Valor Original", how do I reach that?

Comment: Umm, just add `AVG([Valor Original])`?